# How to close ssh (tunel) connection in R?

Tags: r, ssh

I have ssh + tunel connection executed like:

```
target <- paste0("host:3306")
ProxySev <- "name@1.1.1.1"
keyfile <- "path/to/key"
port <- 3307

cmd <- paste0('ssh::ssh_tunnel(ssh::ssh_connect(host = "', 
              ProxySev, '", keyfile ="', keyfile, '"), port = ', port, ', target = "', target, '")')

pid <- sys::r_background(
  args = c("-e", cmd),
  std_out = TRUE,
  std_err = TRUE
)
```

To close it I use `tools::pskill(pid)`, but how to do that **not knowing the `pid`**? Eg without *proper* closing previous connection and trying to run again

```
pid <- sys::r_background(
  args = c("-e", cmd),
  std_out = TRUE,
  std_err = TRUE
)
```

I get the message:

```
Error: System failure for: bind() (Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted)
Execution halted
Warning message:
Disconnecting from unused ssh session. Please use ssh_disconnect()
```

How to use `ssh_disconnect()` in such case? Or how to get `pid` of this background process?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way, but in most OSes, when a daemon process is killed, any sockets it was listening to remain obligated for "a moment", unavailable for another process to start listening on. This is sometimes regardless of how the process stopped. Waiting a few moments (perhaps 10-60 seconds? not sure, it depends) will preclude that error.

Comment: But to find the pid of a process, try the `ps` package, where `ps::ps()` returns a frame with (among others) `$pid` and `$name` (e.g., `"Rterm.exe"` on windows). From this, one can start to infer which process is interesting to you, better informed with (e.g.) `ps::ps_cmdline(ps::ps_handle(pid))` on your candidate `pid`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to infer which process by using tools in the `ps` package. I'll demonstrate with `Sys.sleep` instead of an ssh connection, but the steps should be translatable.

```r
pid <- sys::r_background(args=c("-e", "Sys.sleep(120)"), std_out = FALSE, std_err = FALSE)
procs <- ps::ps()
subset(procs, name == "Rterm.exe")
# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#     pid  ppid name      username    status       user   system        rss         vms created                 ps_handle 
#   <int> <int> <chr>     <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl> <dttm>                  <I<list>> 
# 1 22284  4224 Rterm.exe "myhost\\r2" running    0.0938   0.0156   47214592    68915200 2022-09-21 12:43:32.263 <ps_handl>
# 2  8472 14464 Rterm.exe "myhost\\r2" running    6.5      0.719   267501568   281235456 2022-09-20 21:31:30.642 <ps_handl>
# 3  4224 14464 Rterm.exe "myhost\\r2" running 4768.     272.     1433354240 31551180800 2022-09-17 22:46:15.056 <ps_handl>
pids <- subset(procs, name == "Rterm.exe")$pid
lapply(setNames(nm = pids), function(pid) ps::ps_cmdline(ps::ps_handle(pid)))
# $`22284`
# [1] "c:\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\x64\\Rterm" "-e"                              "Sys.sleep(120)"                 
# $`8472`
# [1] "c:\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\x64\\Rterm.exe" "--ess"                               "--no-save"                          
# $`4224`
# [1] "c:\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\x64\\Rterm.exe" "--ess"                               "--no-save"                          
(tools::pskill(22284))
# [1] TRUE
```

I wrapped `pskill` in parens since its return value (logical indicating if the process was found and killed) is invisible, the parens cause it to be printed.